# Restrict iframe cookies based on host domain

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, setcookie

I have a web app meant to be loaded inside an iframe on different hosts (let's say served from myiframe.com). In order to mantain session I use a cookie named 'session' that is set when the iframe's content is requested the first time, with a domain of myiframe.com.

Now let's say that host A (a.com) loads the iframe and therefore a session cookie is set with domain myiframe.com. If you navigate to host B (b.com) then the same session cookie is used. What I want is that sessions are independant from each other, that you can have a session in A and a different one in B. I.e. that the cookie that is set when requested from A is not used when the app is requested from B.

I think I can use different cookie names depending on the host and then validate the session by matching the appropiate cookie with the host's information, but I was wondering if I could do it somehow using 'set-cookie' header and cookie's domain field.

BTW I have no control over hosts or how they add the iframe, although they all do it the exact same way.

Edit: The request used for getting the iframe content contains more than enough information for reliably identifying the host. That's not an issue.

Comment: _“I.e. that the cookie that is set when requested from A is not used when the app is requested from B”_ - this “from” you are imagining here doesn’t actually exist. _“I have no control over hosts or how they add the iframe”_ - then you are more or less out of luck. The referrer would be the only thing that would allow you to make such a decision then, and how unreliable that is should be known I guess.

Comment: @CBroe I can identify the host making the request with no problem. I edited the question to include that in case it wasn't as clear as I thought

Comment: The iframe isn’t requested by the “host”, but by the browser of the user visiting the website that contains the iframe. I don’t see what exactly you’d want to “identify” in that regard, resp. with what purpose.

Comment: @CBroe Yes you are right, the iframe is not requested by host but by the browser. That was just a way of simplifying and be uselessly verbose and detailed by saying "the host that responds with a web page that adds an iframe element that makes the browser request the iframe content". I just decided to summarize and change that for "the host that requests the iframe"

Comment: Well then where is the actual problem? If you know where the document was iframed, then use a different session cookie name based on that …?

Comment: @CBroe As stated in the question "I think I can use different cookie names depending on the host [...], but I was wondering if I could do it somehow using 'set-cookie' header and cookie's domain field."

Comment: The domain of your cookie is always `myiframe.com` (or subdomains thereof.) You can not set cookies for other domains.

Comment: @CBroe Yep, I also thought it can't be done, but I'm not highly experienced with cookies implementations and their "corner cases" so I decided to get some help. If it cannot be done that's definetly the answer to the question so if you want to add it as such I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set cookies for “other” domains, so your content loaded from `myiframe.com` won’t be able to set a cookie for either `a.com` or `b.com`

If you have a mechanism to determine where your content was embedded via iframe (the referrer would not really work for that, resp. is too unreliable), then you can use different session cookie names to get a different session “for” the iframed content running inside a.com and b.com.